# Check if the network where application was deployed is up and running

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have a Winforms application (written in C#) that is deployed on a network using ClickOnce. Everything works fine and program will check for update on startup.

But if the network is down, when application starts it shows that its checking for new version, but the server is actually down! I want to notify the user that checking for update was not successful. Is there anyway to do that? I already checked but it seems that visual studio does not add any code for this case.

I need the program to be available offline, so setting the program to only online is not a case.

Can someone please tell me how can I do this programatically, or what options I need to change in solution properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out this class?

```
  System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment currentDeployment = System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
```

It gives you access to properties like **UpdateLocation** and **TimeOfLastUpdateCheck** that might be useful for what you are trying to do.